# Raspberry piTFT display gui with python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am using raspberry pi tft display from adafruit. What setting is required for raspberry piTFT display to work with python tkinter?

Answer (score 0):

Python tkinter need XWindow system. You could start it on the PiTFT using :

```
FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb1 startx -- -dpi 60
```

There is a nice tutorial here: http://raspi.tv/2014/texys-2-8-inch-touchscreen-with-raspicamcorder-step-1

Next you can start python tkinter script using :

```
DISPLAY=:0 python <your script>
```

It will be displayed on PiTFT screen.